# Neo4j Find all paths back to the same node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have entities (A, B, C for example) which can send 1 or more protocols (TCP, UDP and FTP) and can receive one or more protocol as shown at the chart below.

I want to create a cypher query that will find all the possible paths from a given entity back to the same entity, ordered from the shortest path to the longest based on the number of hops.

[image]

Can be tested online at [neo4j Console](http://console.neo4j.org/), using the following Create Script:

```
create (a:Entity {name:'A'}), 
(b:Entity {name: 'B'}), 
(c:Entity {name: 'C'}), 
(d:Entity {name: 'D'}),  
(tcp:Protocol {name: 'TCP'}),  
(ftp:Protocol {name: 'FTP'}),  
(udp:Protocol {name: 'UDP'}),  
(a)-[:SEND]->(tcp), (tcp)-[:SEND]->(b), (tcp)-[:SEND]->(d), (b)-[:SEND]->(ftp), (ftp)-[:SEND]->(c), (ftp)-[:SEND]->(d), 
(d)-[:SEND]->(udp), (c)-[:SEND]->(udp), (udp)-[:SEND]->(a)
```

*make sure you click Clear DB at the top bar first*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH path=(source { name:'A' })-[r*4..10]-> source
RETURN path, length(path)/2-1 AS hops
ORDER BY hops
```

Explanation:

`{ name:'A' }` - used to identify the source node

`[4..10]` - used to specify what are the minimal and maximum hops (including). below 4 hops is not possible in this case, since minimum hops are 4:

*Entity -> Protocol -> Entity -> Protocol -> Entity*

`length(path)/2-1 AS hops` - calculates how much Entity Hops exists in path. Note that the `length(path)` contains both entities and protocols.

Comment: You can shorten the query by eliminating the `WITH` clause and changing the immediately following `RETURN` clause to: `RETURN path, relations, length(path)/2-1 AS hops`.